# Python: Search for a string, parse text after that string, add to a list

Tags: python, xml

So I've got a large piece of XML (this, for example: https://www.goodreads.com/author/list/20598?format=xml&key=pVrw9BAFGMTuvfj4Y8VHQ) and I want to search it for each appearance of the string < title >, then parse the text after that to get the actual title and temporarily assign it as the value of a variable, then append add that variable to a list.

In other words, go through this XML and come away with a list titles.

My questions then (and I saw, in searching, lots of thing LIKE this but nothing quite the same):

1-How do I go through that whole body of text, stopping at each appearance of < title > to do the operation I'm describing here?

2-How exactly should I parse that title out? That is, I want to capture the string that occurs betweeen < title > and < /title >?

Pre-emptive thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing it; I took a Python class over two years ago but haven't had any opportunity to put it into practice since then, so my memory has gotten rusty. I suspect part 1 would be a "FOR" operation, right? And then for part 2, I've got to parse-forward 6 spaces and then . . . I'm just drawing a blank.

Comment: First of all, don't try to parse XML yourself.  Instead, use a python XML parser, such as [tag:lxml].

Comment: please show us what you have done so far

Comment: Checkout this [tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) on [tag:lxml], write some code, then come back here with your attempt.

Comment: Read through the [Tutorial in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) and practice the given examples till you have found data structures and flow controls tools that look like they will help you implement your algorithm.  Once you have a handle on that you might want to consider using [```lxml```](http://lxml.de/)

Comment: Okay, I guess. I'm using Komodo Edit for my compiler; should that work okay for all of this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by `<title>` you mean a title *tag*, any halfway-decent XML parser will do this easily: it will let you know when a `title` tag has been found, and then extract the text within that tag (the title you want).

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has mentioned, there are plenty of parsers for XML. However, if you'd like to do it yourself, then here is a function that will work, except for cases where the title element flags (I don't know what they're technically called) appear within commented out text or otherwise illegitimate sections of text.

```
def extract_text_between_flags(inputText, flagBegin, flagEnd):
    # Instantiate an empty list to store the results
    excerpts = list()

    # Find the first occurrence of the begin flag
    indexBegin = inputText.find(flagBegin)
    # Until the begin flag is no longer found
    while indexBegin > -1:
        # From the current begin flag location, search forward to the first
        # occurrence of the end flag
        indexEnd = inputText.find(flagEnd, indexBegin + len(flagBegin)) + len(flagEnd)
        # If the end flag is not found, stop searching
        if indexEnd <= 0:
            break
        # Extract the relevant passage from the text and add it to the list
        excerpt = inputText[indexBegin+len(flagBegin):indexEnd-len(flagEnd)]
        excerpts.append(excerpt)

        # Set the new search starting point as the next occurrence of the
        # begin flag
        indexBegin = inputText.find(flagBegin, indexEnd)

    return excerpts

titles = extract_text_between_flags(myXMLString, '< title >', '< /title >')
```